# How to apply scipy.savgol_filter to pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

In code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(20), index=np.arange(20))

def smooth(x):
    return savgol_filter(x, 7, 3)

s.apply(smooth)
```

I got an error `If mode is 'interp', window_length must be less than or equal to the size of x.`.
The reason I think is `smooth` takes the value row-wisely from `Series`, so it got only 1 value each time which is smaller than the `window_length=7`.

If I use `pd.DataFrame.apply()`, there is a parameter `axis` that can be set to get the correct result.

I also want to avoid using `smooth(s)` which returns a NumPy array instead of pandas.Series.

Is there any way to `.apply()` sav_gol filter on `pandas.Series` directly?

Comment: For a `pandas.Series` `apply` is applied to each element individually, not the series as a whole. Instead you want the `apply` method of `pandas.DataFrame`. You can convert from a `Series` to a `DataFrame` using `s.to_frame` giving `s.to_frame().apply( smooth )` or just `smooth( s ).

Comment: `savgol_filter(s, 7, 3)` ?